# AWS CodeBuild BUILD_CONTAINER_UNABLE_TO_PULL_IMAGE error

Tags: docker, aws-codebuild, aws-secrets-manager

I'm trying to use a custom image in my CodeBuild definition, but it fails with the following error:

> BUILD_CONTAINER_UNABLE_TO_PULL_IMAGE: Unable to pull customer's
> container image. Asm fetching username: AuthorizationData is
> malformed, empty field

The terraform definition is the following:

```
resource "aws_codebuild_project" "apply" {
  name          = local.names.apply_codebuild
  description   = "Responsible for 'apply' of CodeBuild '${local.names.apply_codebuild}'"
  build_timeout = "120"
  service_role  = aws_iam_role.apply.arn

  artifacts {
    type = "CODEPIPELINE"
  }

  environment {
    compute_type                = "BUILD_GENERAL1_SMALL"
    image                       = "docker.cloudsmith.io/myorg/devops/amazonlinux2-custom:latest"
    type                        = "LINUX_CONTAINER"
    image_pull_credentials_type = "SERVICE_ROLE"
    
    registry_credential {
      credential  = "CLOUDSMITH_API_KEY"
      credential_provider = "SECRETS_MANAGER"
    }
  }

  source {
    type = "CODEPIPELINE"
    buildspec = templatefile("${path.module}/buildspecs/apply.yml", {
      SCRIPT           = local.apply_script
      NAME             = var.name
      RUNTIME_VERSIONS = var.runtime_versions
    })
  }
}
```

Any ideas on what might be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Issue was that Cloudsmith asks for both the username and the API-key, not only the API-Key. The CLOUDSMITH_API_KEY secret only contained the API-key. After adding the `username` and the `API-key as password`, it worked.